# Executar query ao pressionar um botão e enviar para o modal

Tags: php, css, sql, ajax, modal

Tenho o seguinte código em que quero clicar em um botão, e ao fazer isso executar uma **Query** e exibir os resultados em um **Modal**

Portanto, o botão:

```
<a class="btn-sm btn-success view_data" data-target="view_data">
```

Página em que executo o sql (Rota teste)

```
$query = ("select... exemplo")
$output = '';
$output .= '
<table class="w3-table-all w3-hoverable">
 <tr>
   <td><b>Nome<b/></td>
 </tr>';
      for ($i = 1; $i < count($query); $i++) {
      $resul = $query[$i]["nam_per_sching_cla"];
      $output .= '
 <tr><td>'. $resul . '</td>
 </tr>';
}
$output .= '</table>';
echo $output;
```

Função jquery com ajax para chamar a página php e enviar os dados para o modal:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.view_data').click(function(){
        var situacao = $(this).attr("dta_sching");

        $.ajax({
            //url:"http://localhost:8080/yogafit/public/teste/util/schedule_class.php",
            url:"{{route('teste')}}",
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            method:"post",
            data:{situacao:situacao},
            success:function(data){
                $("#prop-details").html(data); //Local onde os dados vai ser mostrado, modal no caso
                $('#myModalClass').modal("show");
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalClass" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" style="text-align:center">Turma</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Acontece que ele retorna o modal "vazio" conforme abaixo:

[image: Modal]

Não sei oque posso estar fazendo de errado para que os dados não sejam exibidos no modal.

Answer (score 0):

Tente atualizar após o modal ser exibido.

Para isso pode tratar o evento "show":

```
$('#myModalClass').modal("show");
$('#myModalClass').on('shown', function() {
     $("#prop-details").html(data);
});
```

Se estiver usando *Bootstrap* versão 3, use assim:

```
$('#myModalClass').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
     $("#prop-details").html(data);
});
```

Comment: Olá Ricardo! Mesmo realizando essa alteração o modal é exibido sem as informações

Comment: Passando um texto fixo para o modal pelo jquery, o mesmo funciona. Coloquei um  console.log(data) e ele apresenta uma data (?), e o retorno deveria ser uma tabela.